# How to create a array in python that searches a string for a particular tag and places the output into a return

Tags: python, arrays, function, lambda

Currently i have the below code in python:

```
def get(x):
    up, up1, up2, up3, up4 = "" ,"" ,"","" , ""


    x = x.split(", ")
    for i in x:
        if "Up_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up = str(i) + ', '
        if "Up1_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up1 = str(i) + ', '
        if "Up2_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up2 = str(i) + ', '
        if "Up3_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up3 = str(i) + ', '
        if "Up4_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up4 = str(i) + ', '

    return (str(up) + str(up1) + str(up2) + str(up3) + str(up4))[:-2]
```

although this functions fine for what i have at the moment if any tags where to be added that contained Up_5 onwards to Up10_ then the function would stop working.

What i want to do is put together a function that searches the "tags" column for any tags containing "Up_" & "Up*_" the * (in SQL terms will return anything with a value between the Up & *. Not sure if there is a functionality for this in python) then whatever the array finds is placed in another array that only contains Up* and Up*_ tags then applies this to another column.

```
+---+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| product_id |  sku  | total_sold |   tags    | total_images |
+---+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+
| geggre     | rgerg |        456 | Up1_, Up2 |            5 |
+---+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

want it to look like:

```
+---+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
| product_id |  sku  | total_sold |   tags    | total_images | Count |
+---+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
| ggeggre    | rgerg |        456 | Up1_, Up2 |            5 |     2 |
+---+----------+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
```

I already have the count tag thanks to another user:

data["total_tags"] = data["tags"].apply(lambda x : len(x.split(',')))

I just need to know how to created the above array to simplify my if statements and have it to include upto Up10_ tags too.

also this is my python that uses the get and appends the "tags" column to only include the Up tags:

```
data['tags'] = data['tags'].apply(get)
```

FULL SCRIPT FOR CONTEXT:

```
# impoting padas module with an alias of pd
import pandas as pd


# get function assigned to x (x values: up, up1, up2, up3, up4)
def get(x):
    up, up1, up2, up3, up4 = "" ,"" ,"","" , ""


    x = x.split(", ")
    for i in x:
        if "Up_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up = str(i) + ', '
        if "Up1_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up1 = str(i) + ', '
        if "Up2_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up2 = str(i) + ', '
        if "Up3_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up3 = str(i) + ', '
        if "Up4_" in i:
            # print(i)
            up4 = str(i) + ', '
    # returns the values within a string if each maches, it also removed -2 characters    
    return (str(up) + str(up1) + str(up2) + str(up3) + str(up4))[:-2]
# data contains the content of the data200.csv file using pandas read_csv function
data = pd.read_csv('data200.csv')

#defines the tags column to equal what up_ tags are in the tags column using the get function
data['tags'] = data['tags'].apply(get)

#
data = data[ (data['tags'] == "") == False]

#creates a new column called total_tags and returns a count of how many elements are between commas
data["total_tags"] = data["tags"].apply(lambda x : len(x.split(',')))

# prints first 5 lines of csv
print(data.head())
# exports everything to test.csv and removes the index column
data.to_csv("test.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: Just to clarify you want this as a new column? Or just a function where you insert one `'tags'` element and it returns you the string or what exactly is `x` in your function `get(x)`?

Comment: A function where you insert all the up_ tags that appear in the tags column and returns only them, then the count will function as normal and count the number of elements between the columns

Comment: i've included the full script for context @LeoE

Comment: What is actually the input into your get function? Is Up1_, Up2 your input or output?

Comment: If I understand it correctly it is like a "tag" filter? Where you input any tags and it returns only the `Up*_` tags?

Comment: @LeoE thats exactly what i'm trying to do yes

Comment: See answer, the last lambda expression should work for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
import re

def get(x):
    x = x.split(", ")
    out_str = ''
    for tag in x:
        if re.search("^Up\d*_", tag):
            t = re.match("^Up\d*_", tag)
            t = t.group(0)
            out_str += t + ','
    return out_str[:-1]
print(get("Up1_, AS3_, Up2_, Up_, AS_"))
```

Output:

```
Up1_,Up2_,Up_
```

Is this what you were searching for? If you only want the numbers 0-9 in you tag you can change the `*` in the regex to a `?`:

```
if re.search("^Up\d?_", tag):
     t = re.match("^Up\d?_", tag)
```

## EDIT:

After your edit I know better what you mean and you could simply do:

```
data['tags'] = data['tags'].apply(lambda x : ",".join(re.findall("Up\d*_", x)))
```

Or:

```
data['tags'] = data['tags'].apply(lambda x : ",".join(re.findall("Up\d?_", x)))
```

Depending if you want only a maximum of one digit between `Up` and `_` or if any number of digits is allowed. Please pay attention, that in the `findall()` approach the `^` is removed, since we are not only searching from the beginning of the string, but through the whole string for all occurrences.

## EDIT 2:

Okay to summarize the comments and additional information gained by those comments you probably want something like this:

```
data['tags'] = data['tags'].apply(lambda x : ",".join(re.findall("[Uu]p\d?_\S*(?=,)", x)))
```

Comment: ok this is good, if i want to print the full tag for example the tags are:
Up_Black-Diamond-Heel-Perspex-Mule-Black-Jla004991, Up1_Thick-Oversized-Hoop-Earrings-Gold-Jl40680. would i just add the * at the end of the _ within the below:

```
data['tags'] = data['tags'].apply(lambda x : ",".join(re.findall("Up\d*_", x)))
```

Comment: So you don't only want the `Up*_` part, but the whole tag which has a `Up*_` anywhere in it? No, you have to differentiate the tags, you can have a look at regex101.com for some playing around ;) You could use `"Up\d?_.*(?=,)"` for example as regex

Comment: yeah the whole tag which has up_ or Up*_ anywhere in it

Comment: Okay, lower case as well, please for the future include all of this in your uestion. With the example you gave non of this was clear... Then it comes to this regex: `"[Uu]p\d?_.*(?=,)"`

Comment: no worries apologies, the regex you have given me now includes additonal tags:

Up1_Clear-Strap-And-Perspex-Block-Heel-Sandals-Nude-Jl34501, Up_Mini-Dimante-Hair-Clip-Multipack-Jl42437, [Xl, Xs]

Comment: My mistake use `[Uu]p\d?_\S*(?=,)`

Comment: Great that works! is there any chance you can explain how this full line works : data['tags'] = data['tags'].apply(lambda x : ",".join(re.findall("Up\d?_\S*(?=,)", x)))

Just so im able to comment on the top and try to learn from it! man thanks

Comment: For regex have a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html And please accept the answer, if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Thanks! that's worked and that documentation has been bookmarked. Much appreciated

Comment: What if i want to add an if statment within that code so that if there are no Up_tags it will insert every tag thats not an Up_ tag instead